# AJax form submission, unable to load file

Tags: php, ajax, forms

Making a ajax form submission, call is made but the php script isn't executed.

```
<form method="post" id="uform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Name<input type="text" name="name" required>
URL<input type="file" name="presentation" required>
<button type="submit" value="submit"></button>
</form>
```

script:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("form#uform").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var fd= document.getElementById('uform');
var formData = new FormData(fd);
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
ajax.open("POST", "upload_video_process.php");
ajax.send(formData);
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_FILES['presentation']['name']))
{
//-------Code to be executed
}
else{
echo "error2";
}
```

I get error2 in response means $_FILES['presentation']['name'] isn't set. Don't know what to do.[devtools snap of ajax request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCLsA.png)

Comment: Use enctype='multipart/form-data' in form tag

Comment: sorry, now edited.

Comment: Isnt your `formData` should be a serialize array $( "#uform" ).serialize()

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<form method="post" id="uform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Your form tag is missing 'enctype' attribute which is required if your form have a 'file' input type.

Comment: Form already has a enctype. Check your answer there are 2 enctype used.

Comment: It was missing first so thought that's the problem